# 'import UIKit' caused disappearing a cast error of Double-to-Int. Why ?

Tags: swift, swift-playground

I'm a Swift beginner and I have a question.

I created a new playground file in Xcode6-Beta3 , and erased 

all default snippets generated automatically.
And I wrote following 
one line only,

```
var x:Int = (1.234 as Int)
```

And then, this line caused a compile error with message saying that

```
Playground execution failed: 
error: <EXPR>:1:20: error: 
'Double' is not convertible to 
'Int'
var x:Int = (1.234 as Int)
               ^
```

in the Console Output.
I can understand this error because 1.234 can not be casted as Int.

Next, I added one more line `import UIKit` before `var x:Int = (1.234 as Int)`,

so the codes were following:

```
import UIKit

var x:Int = (1.234 as Int)
```

Then, the error message above disappeared. But I can't understand 

the reason that adding `import UIKit` caused disappearing

the error message claiming that
`'Double' is not convertible to 'Int'`

above.

Please teach me this reason or some references
to understand about it.

Regards.

Comment: Why are you using Xcode 6 beta 3? You should be using beta 7.

Comment: this is also happening for beta 7. I think it is related to bridging with NSNumber

Comment: Thanx. Anyways,I'll update my Xcode asap.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler will always seek a way to make your code compiling as possible as it can. With `import UIKit`, your code is something equivalent to

```
var _x = 1.234 as NSNumber
var x:Int = (_x as Int)
```

The compiler can turn to `NSNumber` when have `UIKit` imported.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I understand converting NSNumber when compiling.